# Contact-Form-7-Not-Sending-Emails Create SMTP Error: data not accepted

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp, contact-form-7

Detailed Error log
Versions:
WordPress: 5.8
WordPress MS: No
PHP: 7.4.22
WP Mail SMTP: 3.0.3

Params:
Mailer: smtp
Constants: No
ErrorInfo: SMTP Error: data not accepted.SMTP server error: DATA END command failed Detail: [95.211.209.81      18] Our system has detected that this message is
likely suspicious due to the very low reputation of the sending IP
address. To best protect our users from spam, the message has been
blocked. Please visit
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/188131 for more information. y30si11926988edi.44 - gsmtp
SMTP code: 550 Additional SMTP info: 5.7.1
Host: aspmx.l.google.com
Port: 25
SMTPSecure: string(0) ""
SMTPAutoTLS: bool(false)
SMTPAuth: bool(false)

Server:
OpenSSL: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017

Debug:
Email Source: Contact Form 7
Mailer: Other SMTP
SMTP Error: data not accepted.
Email Source: WP Mail SMTP
Mailer: Other SMTP
SMTP Error: data not accepted.

SMTP Debug:

2021-08-16 18:03:53 Connection: opening to aspmx.l.google.com:25, timeout=300, options=array()

2021-08-16 18:03:53 Connection: opened

2021-08-16 18:03:53 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 mx.google.com ESMTP y30si11926988edi.44 - gsmtp

2021-08-16 18:03:53 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO [www.xxx.xx](http://www.xxx.xx)

2021-08-16 18:03:53 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [xx.xx.xx.xx]250-SIZE 157286400250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8

2021-08-16 18:03:53 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:admin@xxx.xx

2021-08-16 18:03:53 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 OK y30si11926988edi.44 - gsmtp

2021-08-16 18:03:53 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:yyyy@gmail.com

2021-08-16 18:03:54 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 OK y30si11926988edi.44 - gsmtp

2021-08-16 18:03:54 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA

2021-08-16 18:03:54 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354  Go ahead y30si11926988edi.44 - gsmtp

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Comment: please edit your post and remove unused details and text to simplify your question and pay attention to focus on your main problem and explain more about it to help others answer your question.

Comment: please format your code with code fences to make the code readable. Goodluck 

Answer (score -1):

After running a test on https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx I noted that my IP is blacklisted
The https://flashstart.com/ops-im-blacklisted/ articles gives details of the workaround.

A check on my spf record (https://www.dmarcanalyzer.com/spf/checker/) indicated an error with the preconfigured spf record as below

Problem: We've noticed the following problems with your SPF records.
Warning : You shouldn't use +all mechanisms at all as this would allow all sending IP addresses and making the SPF useless.

So I changed it from v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com +all to
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com -all and that solved my issue